# Telescope Project is crashing

Tags: telescope

I'm new to Meteor and I'm trying to get Telescope running. I took the following steps;

Install Meteor
Install Meteorite
Download or clone Telescope into /some/path
cd /some/path
Run mrt
The application was running fine, but now when I run it, I receive the following error could someone point me in the right direction please :

```
 W20150325-18:30:52.597(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20150325-18:30:52.599(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/DAndre/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.1c3hdcd++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150325-18:30:52.600(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150325-18:30:52.600(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150325-18:30:52.602(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: PostsDailyController is not defined
W20150325-18:30:52.602(-4)? (STDERR)     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app/lib/router/posts.js:81:34), <anonymous>:1:1)
W20150325-18:30:52.602(-4)? (STDERR)     at getDefaultViewController (app/lib/router/posts.js:81:10)
W20150325-18:30:52.602(-4)? (STDERR)     at PostsListController.extend.view (app/lib/router/posts.js:87:28)
W20150325-18:30:52.602(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/DAndre/Desktop/discoverList/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:212:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Comment: I was able to fix it!

Comment: Swifter, what did you do to fix the issue? Others may be interested in following your troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: I removed a file, and I needed that file in order for the application to load. It was an user error!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related to your issue, but you shouldn't need to use Meteorite or the `mrt` command. Meteor has had its own package manager since version 0.9, so you can just do `meteor`.